# Google maps API - distance between two addresses

Tags: java, google-maps

Using Google Maps API how to determine the driving distance between two locations? Platform -Java

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to use the [Google Directions Web Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests). You can make an HTTP request, specifying your two locations as parameters, and get back JSON (or XML) describing the directions between the two points.

**N.B.** The [Google Maps terms of service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_12) explicitly states that using the Google Maps Web Services without putting the results on a Google Map is prohibited.

Comment: That's the distance of the shortest route, not the real distance (as the crow flies)

Comment: Still +1 as this is probably the best bet there is

Comment: There are some [restrictions](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits), you are only allowed to use this webservice when displaying a map. Out of this scope you'll get a [REQUEST DENIED](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Berlin&destination=Munich)

Comment: @seanizer: Since the question asks for the "driving distance", I think "shortest route" is more useful than "as the crow flies" unless you have a tank.

Comment: @JeremyP sorry, didn't see that. And it wouldn't be much help for a tank either, because there may be annoying obstacles like mountains and lakes inbetween :-)

Comment: @all thanks for ur suggestion. BTW I dont want to display the map, I just want retrieve the distance. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new in Java and I had the same issue. That's why I've decided to make a Java library to provide theses information and more like route.

Here's the [link](http://code.google.com/p/geocoder-library/). Tell me what do you think about it and if it was useful for your case.

Comment: A Java Doc and user guide are upcoming :) Your opinions are welcomed.

Comment: Error 404 Page Not Found

Comment: 404, please check!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Directions API:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

The default travel mode is for driving.

Please read the terms of service:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html

Particularly section 10.12 - which refers to using the results from this API. In short, you must display it in conjunction with a Google map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java Google Maps SDK :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code:

```
     /**
     *
     * @param apiKey
     * @param origin
     * @param destination
     * @return
     */
    public static DistanceMatrixRow[] getDistance(String apiKey, String origin, String destination)
    {

        DistanceMatrixApiRequest req = DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey(apiKey)
                .build());

        DistanceMatrix query = req.origins(origin)
                .destinations(destination)
                .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
                .avoid(RouteRestriction.TOLLS)
                .language("en-US")
                .awaitIgnoreError();

        if (query != null && query.rows.length > 0)
        {
            return query.rows;
        } else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```